# do I need to define Fact Table or the Dimension tables?

Tags: ssas, dimension, fact-table, msbi

I am trying to build a data warehouse using the OLTP database and was wondering if I need to define the Fact Tables first or the Dimensions?

Please help?

Regards
Yogi

Comment: Are you asking what should be created first using DML, or what you should designed first?

Comment: yes what should I designed first and if possible what should be created first too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very iterative process, usually you go this way:

1. Gather business requirements
2. Identify facts and dimensions
3. Design
4. Implement

It's of course very simplified. Steps 1-3 usually consume about 80% of whole project and consist of many sub steps.

I recommend you do a reading of Kimball's book on subject:
[http://www.amazon.com/The-Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Dimensional/dp/0471200247](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247)

-- UPDATE

I found another guideline which might lead you through creating successful BI solution:

1. Create a data source
2. Create a data source view
3. Create one or more dimensions
4. Create a cube
5. Deploy the database

This will lead you to conclusion that you need to have dimensions and facts already in place. This is right and wrong.

You might find that it is impossible to gather all the requirements at once, so what you should start with is (and create tables accordingly):

1. Identify & create dimensions
2. Identify & create facts
3. Connect those, add cube calculations, KPIs whatever required

[Source](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/five-basic-steps-for-implementing-an-analysis-services-database/)

Repeat steps 1-3 as you learn more from your customer.

This repetitive nature comes from various factors. Customers are not always aware of all their requirements, sometimes those might not even be functional ones, so how could they know. We as DEVs are not domain experts, usually we learn as we go.

Answer (score 0):

In most simple language Dimensions are the properties on which you would like to filter your data.. Whereas fact table contains actual data linked with primary key of dimensions.

Would recomend you to gather bussiness requirements first and collect list of OLTP colums and then sit to decide the your model.

Also read some writeups on data modeling and identify the best dimensional model (star or snowflake)for your application.